# Yahoo YQL RSS returning no results

Tags: javascript, rss, yql, yahoo-api

I'm having a bit of issue with YQL. I'm trying to query an RSS from a URL but I get no results.

Entered this query:

```
select title from rss where url="http://www.spoilertv.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Aftermath"
```

...and instead of getting the titles as requested, the console shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2017-02-23T17:13:16Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
        <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
        <url execution-start-time="1" execution-stop-time="101"
            execution-time="100" id="5080cef9-75a4-4356-9b08-1d68fb3d855d"><![CDATA[http://www.spoilertv.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Aftermath]]></url>
        <user-time>118</user-time>
        <service-time>100</service-time>
        <build-version>2.0.84</build-version>
    </diagnostics> 
    <results/>
</query>
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When I made a few requests to your URL sample using YQL, I have two results, getting the results in JSON or XML it was always *NULL*.

According to this [link](https://forums.developer.yahoo.net/discussion/7436/can-yql-be-used-to-output-rss-or-atom):

> YQL produces only xml or json. You can create rss or atom feed but it
>   always will be inside yql root element. So you need another one tool
>   to extract a feed from response. I'm using Google Apps Script for
>   that. It can parse and create xml/rss and uses server-side javascript
>   e.g:

```
var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=...'; // rest query to YQL table
var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(); // this is an xml string
var root = XmlService.parse(xml).getRootElement(); // now we can modify this xml or create a new one.
```

What I suggest you is make the following test instead:

Check this [link](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_code_tutorials.html) and follow the step #6:

> Click Copy URL. From yql_news_app.html, paste the URL into the src
>   attribute of the second script tag as seen below *which in your case
>   you can check as follows*:

```
<body>
  <div id='results'></div>
  <escript src='https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20title%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spoilertv.com%2Ffeeds%2Fposts%2Fdefault%2F-%2FAftermath%22&diagnostics=true'>
  </escript>
</body>
```

In your browser, press F12 *(and check the Console tab)*. see if there're errors. If so, please update you question with the details of the results.